# Can we update JSON files on the fly in Angularjs?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-model

Angular JS seems to have a problem updating content in .json files on the fly. Specifically I have to restart the server (locally) in order for angular to recognise the new data. This seems to be how Angularjs runs it's model domain, but if I want to CRUD JSON data will I have the problem I have to restart the server? Note I'm working locally but want to avoid dev time to verify this - especially if it's a known issue.

Comment: Can you give some reproduction steps? For example, some code for the factory or service you are using to make the rest GET/read call. As well, what low-level service are you using to make the calls? $http, restAngular or others? Finally, what does your rest resource look like? (r)GET /resource/id, (c)POST /resource/id, (u)PUT /resource/id, (d)DELETE /resource/id... etc.

Comment: Sure, if you refer to the angularjs tutorial on their github (step 12 for example) the above should be replicable: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_12

Answer (score 0):

This is just a cache issue! Clear Cache in Browser, phew! Crtl + shift + del on Firefox to the rescue! Much more in keeping with the times ;-)